# Compress every file in a directory into its own compressed file

Tags: linux, tar

How do I compress every file in a directory into its own tar whilst preserving the name for each file?

i.e.
file1.out
file2.out

-->

file1.out.tar.gz
file2.out.tar.gz

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Putting every file into a separate tar file doesn't make any sense in this scenario. You can use `gzip` to compress them directly:

```
gzip *
```

will result in `file1.out.gz`, `file2.out.gz` etc.

You would use `tar` only if you would need a compressed archive as a single file.

If you ineed need a tar archive for every file, you can create it like so:

```
for i in *; do tar -czf $i.tar.gz $i; done
```

Comment: +1 - There is no reason to create a tar (Tape ARchive) for a single file. Just compress what you want to compress - the result will be marginally smaller, and make infinitely more sense to people extracting the files.

Comment: To tar each individual subdirectory (only one level deep) and remove the original: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -path . | while read a_dir; do tar -zcvf ${a_dir}.tgz ${a_dir} --remove-files; done`

Comment: (can't edit my comment above after 5 min) A simpler/safer version: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar -zcvf {}.tgz {} --remove-files \;`

Comment: And `gzip -d *` to unzip `.gz` files

Answer (score 12):

To build on @SvenW's answer (which will only work on the current directory), if you have a HUGE number of files or want to do it on a recursive directory structure you can also use

```
find . -type f -exec gzip \{\} \;
```

and if you need to put the output into a different directory (in this example, `../target`) and don't want to remove the originals, you can do something like:

```
find . -type f -print | while read fname ; do
    mkdir -p "../target/`dirname \"$fname\"`"
    gzip -c "$fname" > "../target/$fname.gz"
done
```

Comment: `find . -type f -exec gzip {} \;` will be sufficient. The second code will fail with filenames containing spaces and the like.

Comment: Some shells don't like bare {}s, and the second one does something markedly different than the first (and I was aware of the spacing issues but that is kind of tricky to deal with).

Comment: If you know such a shell, I invite you to answer my question over here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/gnu-find-and-masking-the-for-some-shells-which . Nobody was able to name something which is today in use so far.  If you are aware of a risk of your answer, it might be a good idea to name it in your answer.

Comment: @userunknown I was brought up on (t)csh, which had quite a lot of trouble with unescaped curly braces at one time, although it doesn't appear to anymore (but I still escape `{}` as a force of habit). Others have already posted those as answers to your question, however.

Comment: Or, to compress all non-binary files: `find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -exec gzip {} \;`

Comment: A parallel version of the command in my comment above: `find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P 16 gzip` running on 16 CPUs, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
for fich in *; do
    if [ "$fich" != "*" ] ; then
        gzip -9 -c $fich > $fich.tar.gz
        \mv $fich.tar.gz $fich
    fi
done
```