# How to do a Batch file that get all files in a directory and zip it?

Tags: windows, batch

i would like to know how to get all single .bak (or anyother extension) files into a directory, and zipping them (one by one) and save them using the same name, changing only extension.

Thanks

Comment: Going to need more information than that, or clarify the question. What do you mean by "all single files into a directory" and from where?

Comment: Suppose i have a directory with 100 bak files: i would like to zip all 100 files (into 100 different zip archive).

Comment: SvenW: the first one.. file1.bak into file1.zip, file2.bak into file2.zip

Answer (score 4):

For unixoid systems, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/357066/compress-every-file-in-a-directory-into-its-own-compressed-file/357067#357067).

On Windows, try something like this in `cmd.exe`:

```
for %f in (*.bak) do zipper_software %f %f.zip
```

The exact syntax for this command will depend on the zip software you use. Note that you likely will end up with archive file names like file1.bak.zip.

Comment: This was what I was going to suggest, but kudos for this answer.